# Dropbox - Check for token valability

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

As far as I can tell, the `access_token` received from `Dropbox API` doesn't expire. I want to build an application based on this service.
Is there a way to check if the access token has expired?

Comment: Yes, if you have set the tokens life length. (you also have to keep track of that). Or use an existing OAuth implementation for the language of your choice. Just have something to keep track.

Comment: What is the method for checking the token? I didn't found it in the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call an API method to check. E.g. [`/account/info`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#account-info).

Comment: And this will give me an error if the token is expired?

Comment: Yes, though tokens effectively don't expire. If a token stops working, it's much more likely to be because the user unlinked the app via dropbox.com or by deleting an app folder.